# How to get a Checkbox value in Velocity for a customfield

Tags: velocity, jira-plugin

In JIRA I have a custom field which is a Checkbox. In Velocity I'm trying to get the value of the checkbox, but I just seem to get the Name of customfield returned instead of the value:

```
#set($Exclude = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10108").getValue($issue))
```

This is returned for all records, regardless of whether the checkbox is ticked or not:

> [Exclude]

(this is the label of the checkbox)

I also tried the following with no luck:

```
 #set($Exclude = $customFieldManager.getValueFromIssue("customfield_10108", $issue))
```

I don't really care what comes back (0,1 or True/False).

I've also tried this with a Radio Button rather than a Checkbox, but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This took me much more time than it should, but finally found it:

```
#set($Exclude = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10108"))
#if(!$Exclude.hasValue($issue))
<whatever you want to do when the checbox is not checked>
#end
```